# Sort by length of column

Tags: sorting, unix, cygwin

Need help sorting by length of the 4th column with a Unix command.

Example data (all data is made up, and not actual).

```
5032:Stack:overflows@business.com:123:JamesPeterson
3200:Admin:admin@me.com:12ej3dij23i2j32:AdminAdmin
1024:GregoryJames:greg@admin.com:12329232:GregJames
```

Preferred format (Because the length of 4th column is the longest).

```
3200:Admin:admin@me.com:12ej3dij23i2j32:AdminAdmin
1024:GregoryJames:greg@admin.com:12329232:GregJames
5032:Stack:overflows@business.com:123:JamesPeterson
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `awk` to add a column containing the length of the column, sort by that, then remove it.

```
awk -F: '{printf("%d %s\n", length($4), $0)}' input.txt | sort -nr | cut -d' ' -f2- > output.txt
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect!